# Twilio, how to get Child Sid from Parent Sid?

Tags: twilio

please anybody has any solution regarding this? I have got parent sid from but i want child sid to get call duration. Or is it possible to get child sid separately using other parameter/ independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can find the child calls from a parent SID by using the [Calls list resource and filtering by `ParentCallSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#list-filters).

Something like (with Node.js) this:

```
client.calls.list({
    parentCallSid: parentCallSid
},
    calls => console.log(calls);
);
```

And in PHP

```
$sid    = "your_account_sid";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$calls = $twilio->calls->read(array(
    "parentCallSid" => $parentCallSid
));
```

Comment: thank man, but if i am asking more sorry but i really want the php syntax. :) thanks again.

Comment: Added the PHP example. Check out the docs for more examples in PHP: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#list-filters